# Is there any software or tool for installing the operating system automatically?

Tags: operating-system

Our internet data center have many dedicated servers, is there any software of tools for install operating system for them?

I mean, in our data center, there are many dedicated servers, every one has `ipmi` and network card, in general, we use ipmi login a page use remote control for installing operating system, there are many things need we do, such as make partition, choose timezone manually?.

but we think this is troublesome and use too much time, whether there is a convenient software or tool for installing the operating system automatically?

Comment: As a general rule, this is highly dependent on your platform of choice.  I suggest communicating with your OS vendor and seeing what options they offer.  Other than Microsoft (who offers a positively insane number of ways to do this with Windows), there's generally one system specific option for whatever OS you use.

Comment: If i use windows，is there any recommand tools?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the various tools provided by [HashiCorp](https://www.hashicorp.com/) these include:

- [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) - lets you come up with a recipe for your development environment including OS, Settings, Tools & Users.
- [Packer](https://www.packer.io/) - to take those recipes and generate machine images
- [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) - Write, Plan, and Create Infrastructure as Code
- Vault - for security
- Consul - Service Mesh Made Easy
- Nomad - For Deployment.

Comment: I saw the Vagrant apply to virtual machines, but ours are dedicated servers, does it work for this?

Comment: @aircraft - You use Vagrant to set-up and test your environment in VMs, (and those VMs for developing you code). _This gives you a recipe for what OS, with what settings, users & tools in a plain text file._ You can then use the other tools to expand on that to give machine images and to deploy them to your physical severs.